# Use Join perl function to create variables

Tags: perl

I am trying to do some thing like this:

```
my @Amode=('1','2','3');
my @Bmode=('1','2','3');
my @Cmode=('1','2','3');
my @Atemp=('1','2','3');
my @Btemp=('1','2','3');
my @Ctemp=('1','2','3');

my @mode=('A','B','C');
foreach (@mode) {
    my $newmode = join("",$_,mode);
    my $newtemp = join("",$_,temp);
}
```

I want to access the @Amode information through $newmode. Is this possible?

Comment: You're sort of mixing two metaphors.  Symbolic references can be manipulated but not in terms of lexical variables (my variables).  And for what you're doing, it's the wrong way anyway.  Using symbolic references as a poor-man's real refs opens up a can of worms... no... a refuse dumpster full of worms.  Save symbolic refs for Exporter, Memoize, and other "magic" code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't string together variable names, but you can make hash keys and access them.

E.g.

```
my %data = ( "A" => \@Amode, "B" => \@Bmode, "C" => \@Cmode );
my @mode = ("A", "B", "C");

for (@mode) {
    print @{$data{$_}};
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I see what you are trying to do there, but honestly I think you are making it more convoluted than it needs to be.

Why not use hashes?

```
my $modes = {
   'A' => [1,2,3],
   'B' => [1,2,3],
   'C' => [1,2,3],
};
foreach my $mode (keys %$modes){
    ... do something with $modes->{$mode};
}
```